# Why isn't this JQuery Color Picker plugin not getting included/detected in my webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, color-picker, jquery-color

**[JSFiddle here.](https://jsfiddle.net/dnezny00/)**

I am trying to include [this JQuery plugin](http://www.virtuosoft.eu/code/jquery-colorpickersliders/) ([Github](https://github.com/istvan-ujjmeszaros/jquery-colorpickersliders)) into my a web page. But it seems to Not get included.

I checked [this demo page](https://github.com/istvan-ujjmeszaros/jquery-colorpickersliders/blob/master/index.html), particularly their `<head>` tag to see what they have included, and so included `JQuery`, `tinycolor.js`, and `jquery.colorpickersliders.js` (the other scipts included like prettify.js and bootstrap.js don't seem to have an effect - I tested that by removing those `<script>` tags from their demo).

Then I tool the first example code snippet from their [tutorial/guide here](http://www.virtuosoft.eu/code/jquery-colorpickersliders/), and used it. **The problem is that it does not seem to work. What am I missing?**

**index.php:**

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-colorpickersliders-master/jquery-colorpickersliders/jquery.colorpickersliders.css" />
    <script src="jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-colorpickersliders-master/libraries/tinycolor.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-colorpickersliders-master/jquery-colorpickersliders/jquery.colorpickersliders.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <span class="hsl-demo">...</span>
    <script>
        $(".hsl-demo").colorPickerSliders({
            flat:true,
            previewformat:'hsl',
            order: {
                hsl : 1,
                preview : 2
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

```js
$(".hsl-demo").colorPickerSliders({
  
   flat:true,
  
   previewformat:'hsl',
  
   order: {
    hsl : 1,
    preview : 2
   }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://github.com/istvan-ujjmeszaros/jquery-colorpickersliders/blob/master/jquery-colorpickersliders/jquery.colorpickersliders.js"></script>

<script src="https://github.com/istvan-ujjmeszaros/jquery-colorpickersliders/blob/master/libraries/tinycolor.js"></script>

<link href="https://github.com/istvan-ujjmeszaros/jquery-colorpickersliders/blob/master/jquery-colorpickersliders/jquery.colorpickersliders.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<span class="hsl-demo">...</span>
```

---

***EDIT:***

The error in console is:

```
Timestamp: 4/28/2016 11:05:52 AM
Error: TypeError: $(...).colorPickerSliders is not a function
Source File: http://localhost/Tests/Test1/index.php
Line: 17
```

Line 17 is the beginning of the `<script>` tag in the `<body>` tag.

---

***EDIT 2:***

[image]

Comment: @GauravAggarwal Just copy-pasted it in the question. Please see the edit at the bottom of the question.

Comment: in you fiddle the links of included files are not appropriate...

Comment: @GauravAggarwal Why not? Secondly I downloaded the entire archive from Github and then wrote a test webpage. I placed those files in the directory. Not working.

Comment: but try opening the link in new window it opens github page instead of source file

Comment: @GauravAggarwal Oh yes they Are Github links. How do I find the link of the source file? (sorry, my bad)

Answer (score 4):

Try to upper case the 'c' in colorPickerSlider to make the code

```
$(".hsl-demo").ColorPickerSliders({
    flat:true,
    previewformat:'hsl',
    order: {
        hsl : 1,
        preview : 2
    }
});
```

*Note:Never try to include the libraries from github repo directly ,because the resource is read as text/html from github repo over the net. instead try consuming the resource from a CDN.*

[Live Demo @ JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dnezny00/1/)

Comment: I just don't know how do people find CDN links. Can you tell me how I could find a CDN link of this plugin?

Comment: Secondly your demo doesn't seem to work. It shows the same three dots in the output (instead of a color picker) =( Posted a screenshot in the question